# Is it possible to change a binding of an Emberjs object property after it's been instantiated?

Tags: data-binding, ember.js

This doesn't seem to work
http://jsfiddle.net/8haXN/7/

```
App.president = Ember.Object.create({
    name: "Barack Obama",
    name2: "George Bush"
});

App.country = Ember.Object.create({
    presidentNameBinding: 'App.president.name'
});

App.country.set('presidentNameBinding', 'App.president.name2');
App.country.presidentName //stil returns 'Barack Obama'
```

What I'm really trying to do is to change the contentBinding of a CollectionView from one ArrayController to another. Is that possible or is it a bad idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to manually bind this way:

```
App.country.bind('presidentName', Em.Binding.from('App.president.name2'));
```

Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/efPGF/

To read more about bindings, I recommend looking at the old Sproutcore wiki: http://wiki.sproutcore.com/w/page/12412963/Runtime-Bindings.  Just remember to change SC prefix to Ember.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, jsfiddle link didn't work for so I updated it: http://jsfiddle.net/efPGF/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use `Ember.bind`, see http://jsfiddle.net/8haXN/8/

```
App = Em.Application.create()
App.president = Ember.Object.create({
    name: "Barack Obama",
    name2: "George Bush"
});

App.country = Ember.Object.create({
    // Ending a property with 'Binding' tells Ember to
    // create a binding to the presidentName property.
    presidentNameBinding: 'App.president.name'
});

App.someController = Em.Object.create({
    change: function() {
        Ember.bind(App, 'country.presidentName', 'App.president.name2');
    }
});​
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It's good to know there are multiple ways to set/change a binding!

Comment: Although in my existing Ember.js applications, there was no need for manually changing a binding the way you asked for. I almost always just change the actual content of the controller instead of creating a new binding. Did you ask for a general way of changing a binding or do you have a specific issue you want to solve with this?